# Page of repeats itself with script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm learning PHP for a little project, and with mysql I made a little table that updates itself every second from the mysql table.

```
<!Doctype html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Pagina de prueba Mysql</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        padding: 10pt;
        margin:auto 10pt;
    }
    .present {
        background-color: green;
        font-size: 20pt;
    }
    .absent {
        background-color: red;
        font-size: 20pt;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Prueba Mysql</h1>

<?php
    $servername = '192.168.0.101';
    $username = 'dpto';
    $password = 'n1nj4g41d3n';
    $dbname = 'dpto';
// Crear conexion
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn -> connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed> ' . $conn->connect_error);
}
else {echo 'Connection succesfull';}
print '<br>';
// Seleccionar weas
$sql_Jose = 'Select presente from dpto where id=2';
$sql_Lucas = 'Select presente from dpto where id=1';
$Lucas = $conn->query($sql_Lucas)->fetch_object()->presente;
$Jose = $conn->query($sql_Jose)->fetch_object()->presente;
if ($Lucas == 0) {$_Lucas = "<td class='absent'> Lucas </td>";}
else {$_Lucas = "<td class='present'> Lucas </td>";}
if ($Jose == 0) {$_Jose = "<td class='absent'> Jose </td>";}
else {$_Jose = "<td class='present'> Jose </td>";}


?>
<div id='tabla'>
<table>
    <tr><?php echo $_Lucas ?></tr>
    <tr><?php echo $_Jose ?></tr>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function () {
    var updater = setTimeout (function () {
        $('div#tabla').load ('index.php#tabla', 'update=true');
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
</body>
```

The script at the end prints out a second "Prueba Mysql" and "Connection succesful", the table just prints once..

How can I make it so everything is just once on the page?

Comment: Question is not that clear! Do you mean your page will load once but subsequent execution will happen in every second?

Comment: the table only prints once because it is in a div which has  an id whereas <h1> and echo will be repeated because there can be more than 1 <h1>. however in case of div, there is id tabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready (function () {
            refreshTable();
        });
        function refreshTable(){
            setTimeout (function () {
                $('div#tabla').load ('index.php#tabla', 'update=true')
                .always(refreshTable);
            }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem with below script, whenever page is loaded the setTimeout script is trigger and its reload the page.

So its looping again, put the validation to check url have redirected from the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function () {
    var updater = setTimeout (function () {
        $('div#tabla').load ('index.php#tabla', 'update=true');
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```